# JavaFX - accessing data over multiple stages/scenes

Tags: javafx, getter-setter

I can set a label to fxmlMain.fxml from a textfield in fxmlLogIn.fxml via the logInEvent.

My question is how do I access the same value from fxmlLogIn.fxml into a stage/scene that will still be opened later.

My idea is to make more classes that will pass the data for every stage/scene but I know that would not be the right way.

FxmlControllerLogIn.java

```
 @FXML
 private void logInEvent(ActionEvent event)
 {
      FromUsers fromUsers = new FromUsers (fxTxtUserName.getText());

      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
      loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/scenes/fxmlMain.fxml"));
      loader.load();
      Parent mainMenuParent = loader.getRoot();
      FxmlControllerMain fxmlcontrollermain = loader.getController();

      fxmlcontrollermain.setChosenUser(fromUsers);

      Stage logIn = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
      Scene mainMenuScene = new Scene(mainMenuParent);
      Stage mainMenuStage = new Stage();

      mainMenuStage.setScene(mainMenuScene);
      mainMenuStage.setTitle("Main");
      mainMenuStage.setResizable(false);
      mainMenuStage.centerOnScreen();
      mainMenuStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/image.png"));

      logIn.close();

      mainMenuStage.show();
 }
```

FromUsers.java

```
public class FromUsers
{
    private String userName;

    public FromUsers(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

FxmlControllerMain.java

```
public void setChosenUser(FromUsers chosenUser)
{
    fxLblUser.setText(chosenUser.getUserName());
    this.chosenUser = chosenUser;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That basically looks like the correct approach; you are creating a "model" class (`FromUsers`) to store the data and sharing the instance among your controllers. Note that you don't need a different class for each piece of data, you can have a single class with multiple properties and just share one instance. If you need a lot of this kind of functionality, consider using a dedicated framework, such as [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/).

Comment: Thanks. For now I'll stick to my own simple idea. That dedicated framework is still too advanced for me. I have to study more.